# UICollectionViewCell with UIImageView hidden

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have used [this](https://github.com/ashfurrow/Collection-View-in-a-Table-View-Cell) as an example on how to put a UICollectionView in an UITableViewCell and I've replaced the standard UICollectionViewCell with a custom one that has an UIImageView inside it.

The only problem is that in the method collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: where I'm setting the image to be shown, the cell has the hidden property true, although I've never set it as that and setting it to false doesn't work.

I really have no idea why this is happening and I've even set an image in the IB to be shown and not even that is shown.

Hope that I was clear and I'm ready to provide code examples if anyone has a clue.

Comment: please explain it briefly

Comment: @GaneshKumar Custom collection view cell with an imageview inside is marked as hidden although I'm never setting that property true. The collection view is inside a table view cell.